# Expected a "{" but found a ")". Block statements must be enclosed in "{" and "}" in Asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

**ContestM ->Model's  property**

```
public SelectList EmployeeList { get; set; }
public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
```

**Controller action**
On button click from main view,this action is being hit and at the end after processing data for dropdown from db ,i assigning value to dropdown object and trying to display the value in partial view

```
public ActionResult AssignContest()
        {
            try
                {
                int id = 3;
                var res = ContestVM.getTLEmployees(id).ToList();
                var eList = new ContestM();
                eList.EmployeeList = new SelectList(res, "EmployeeId", "FirstName");
                return PartialView("Assign", new ContestM() { EmployeeList = eList.EmployeeList });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ViewData["error"] = ex.Message.ToString();
                    return View("~/Views/Shared/LogoutOrInvalid.cshtml");
                }
        }
```

**my Razor view (assign.cshtml)**

```
@model Performance.Launcher.Models.ContestM
@using (Html.BeginForm("AssignContest", "Contest", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmContestAssignContest" })))
{
    //var emplistdata= ViewData["employeesList"];
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Contest</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ContestId)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployeeId, Model.EmployeeDet, "Choose...", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-2" } })
                //@Html.DropDownList("dropdown1", ViewData["employeesList"])
                //@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Not able to find where i am going wrong .Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly does the exception occur?

Comment: `@using (Html.BeginForm("AssignContest", "Contest", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmContestAssignContest" })))`
you have placed an extra brace at end remove it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have an extra `)` on the end of this line:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AssignContest", "Contest", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmContestAssignContest" })))
```

By the way, if you want to know how I figured it out so fast, I just used my browser's "find" and searched for ")" until I found one that didn't have a matching "(" before it, *and* it was right before a `{`, so I knew that was the one.  You should take error messages for what they mean; a lot of the time they're pretty clear and helpful.